# Combination GFCI/AFCI Breaker not working when replacing regular breaker

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, gfci, afci

First time posting.

I'm doing some upgrades to our house electrical. We live in a 1950s home. An electrician recommended I replace the old breakers on ungrounded circuits off the house sub-panel with combination GFCI/AFCI breakers. Here are the ones I've purchased: http://w3.usa.siemens.com/powerdistribution/us/en/product-portfolio/circuit-breakers/residential-circuit-breakers/Pages/Dual-Function.aspx. We have a mix of 15A and 20A breakers.

Generally, I haven't had any issues replacing the breakers. I've done several and they all work as expected. However, one breaker slot on the sub-panel is behaving strangely. The slot works as expected with the old breaker. But when replacing the old breaker with the new GFCI breaker, it won't flip into the ON position. It seems that nothing is wrong with the new breaker itself: two new breakers of the same type exhibit the same behavior in that slot, but work as expected in another slot. The instructions that come with the new breaker suggest this issue happens when no power is getting to it, but that doesn't make sense to me since the old breaker works fine in that position.

To be clear, the new breaker doesn't appear to be tripping. It never is able to switch on to begin with.

Does this ring any bells? Any troubleshooting tips appreciated.

EDIT: I was using Seimans Breakers when I should have been using GE Breakers approved for use in my particular panel. After replacing with the correct type of breakers, everything works as expected in all the original positions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a ground fault or arc fault is being detected on the circuit, remove the load and see if it will turn on. If it turns on without the load connected you have a problem on that branch circuit. Make sure if you install 3 prong outlets to label them GFCI protected no equipment ground.

Comment: Yes, you could also try moving that branch circuit's hot+neutral to a GFCI that is in a different breaker space.

Comment: Good suggestions, will attempt later today and update. Thanks!

Comment: So I moved the breaker and the circuit's neutral and hot to a different position and everything is working as expected. What could that mean about that other position?

Comment: I have not had this problem on a Siemens panel , can you remove the bkr and take a photo of the contacts that connect to the breaker. I have seen problems with older brands no longer available but not with this brand. The only thing I can think of is a eroded or damaged contact area could cause an AFCI to trip.

Comment: It's actually an old GE panel. I've included a link to photos of it along with a close up of the empty slot: https://imgur.com/a/7bbiY

Comment: Now that I resolved the first issue by moving the hot/neutral with the breaker to a new spot, putting in more new breakers I'm discovering the same thing on a couple other circuits, which seems more like a problem with the branch circuits. There are actually two other breakers/slots here now that are exhibiting the same behavior as the original position described above. One issue I was able to solve by replacing an outlet that seem to be causing a ground fault. So I think there's more sleuthing to be done.

Comment: @NathanG *Wait, what???* Are these breakers **listed** to work in this panel?  Do you have documentation with the breaker which lists your panel type as supported, or that claims to replace a GE breaker type listed in the panel?  If not, this is a huge problem, many breaker types can be forced into other panels, but they don't *fit* and will give serious problems.  General Electric is still in business and continues to support their panels, and GE makes DF breakers for GE panels, at sane price last I looked.

Comment: Oof. Nope, they are not listed. Boy, I feel dumb #newhomeowner. These do seem to fit snugly into place, so didn't think twice about it after installing the first one. But I wonder if actually installing GE breakers will solve my original problem. Regardless, guess I've got to get back to the store and get  the correct breakers.

Comment: Happy to report that with the correct breakers installed, everything is working as expected in all of the original positions. Woohoo. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh, I had that feeling when I heard it was a GE panel.  Yes, it's an interesting characteristic of an arc-fault breaker that they can detect arcs *just outside* their official protection zone, i.e. the clip not quite contacting the bus.